# Force to buy app with old version of Android

Tags: applications, google-play-store, nexus-4, htc-desire, unrooting

I have two smartphones:

- HTC Desire (unrooted / android 2.2 / normal-sim / operator1 / my account)
- Nexus 4 (android 4.4.4 / micro-sim / operator2 / my account)

Both smartphone are regurarly  logged with the same account.

I need to buy some apps with normal-sim from operator1 but those app are available only for android 4.0 and newest.

I will use the apps on my Nexus 4 but I do not want to root any device by now.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT after reading your comments:

AFAIK, It's not possible.

Comment: It is the opposite: I want to buy with HTC desire (android 2.2) and use the app with nexus 4 (android 4.4)

Comment: @Ale Edited. :)

Comment: The apps are not available for Android 2.2, so I can't buy the apps on Play Store from HTC Desire

Comment: @Ale **both smartphone are logged with my account** What happens when you try buying from Nexus??

Comment: With Nexus I can buy it normally (but I have to pay with credit card, while with HTC Desire I can pay with operator offers...)

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. I don't know :(

Answer (score 1):

I assume that rooting and flashing a ICS rom on your HTC desire is out of the question, so how about you take the SIM card from your HTC to your nexus 4, complete the offer, then switch back? If the offer is tied to the **operator** the nexus 4 should be able to make the purchase just fine.

If the offer is tied to the **device model** (HTC), then try [this app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2146216) on your nexus 4 (requires root!). It will make the play store see your nexus 4 as a HTC device. Combined with switching SIM it should satisfy both operator and device requirement for the offer. I'm not sure if it will work for your particular case though.

Comment: The sim format are different (micro sim in N4 and standard sim on HTC) and I do not want to put another sim on my N4...

Comment: You can always cut your sim to the smaller standard and use an adapter when you need to use it on your older phone. Any phone shop can do this for cheap.

Also, you can flash an ICS rom on your HTC, but it's an arduous process. 

The question is, is the offer really worth the trouble? :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the offers you have work, but could you go to the play store in a browser and buy them there on your HTC and tell it to install them on the N4? I've had to do that for devices since you cannot access the Devices page from the app itself. If necessary, you may have to clear defaults with the browser and Play Store so that you have the option of viewing it in a browser instead of being taken directly to the app. I haven't used 2.2 in almost 4 years, but I assume that that is possible.